# Multidimensional array in C with some math.h

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

The code I have so far for setting up my array is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(float myArray[4][3]);

int main(void)
{

    };

    printArray(sides);

    return 0;
}

void printArray(float passedArray[4][3])
{
    printf("Side A\tSideB\tSide C\n");

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            printf("%.3f \t", passedArray[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I've also created a way to evaluate the hypotenuse in a previous code if I was given an input from the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>


double hypotenuse(double lengtha, double lengthb);


int main() // Start of main function
{
    double lengtha, lengthb; //storing variables for later use

    printf("Enter the length of side A: \n"); //Prompt user for input of A

    scanf("%lf", &lengtha); //Stores input from user

    printf("Enter the length of side B: \n\n"); // Prompt user for input of B

    scanf("%lf", &lengthb); //Stores input from user

    return 0; // terminate
} /* End function main */


double hypotenuse(double sidea, double sideb)
{
    return sqrt(pow(sidea, 2) + pow(sideb, 2));
} /* End function */
```

The main issue that' I'm running into however though, is I'm unsure how to take the pre stored values from my first code/arrays, throw them into the equation, then have them output into side c into the table. I know there has a to be a way, but it's really hard to find too much info since C is a bit older. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: alternative to `sqrt(pow(sidea, 2) + pow(sideb, 2));` --> `hypot(sidea, sideb);`. `hypot()` is a standard function.

Comment: You should learn about `struct`. This provides a way to give names to your data rather than using numerical indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you could just iterate over every row of your array and assign the result of the function call to the last column:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    array[i][2] = hypotenuse(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: Internet hero my friend! This is what happens when you stare at something too long lol. Thank you so much! Had to edit a bit to make my hypotenuse work but you pointed me in the right direction and now I have a beautiful output!